# An AVL-tree based order statistic tree in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, set

I have this **`java.util.Set`** implementation that is based on AVL-trees, which implies that the set is sorted. However, it provides two additional operations:

- **`get(int i)`**returns the **`i`**th smallest element in the set, and
- **`indexOf(Object o)`** returns the **rank** of the object **`o`** (the rank of the smallest element is 0, the rank of the second smallest element is 1, and so on).

The AVL-tree structure and the two above operations turn this set into an order statistic tree; both **`get(int)`** and **`indexOf(Object)`** run in worst-case time \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$.

**`OrderStatisticSet.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for an order statistic set. An order statistic
 * set is a sorted set that provides two additional methods:
 * <ul>
 *   <li><code>get(int index)</code> returns the <code><index</code>th smallest
 *       element,</li>
 *   <li><code>indexOf(T element)</code> returns the index of the input element.
 *   </li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 16, 2016)
 */
public interface OrderStatisticSet<T> extends Set<T> {

    /**
     * Returns the <code>index</code>th smallest element from this set.
     * 
     * @param index the element index.
     * @return the <code>index</code>th smallest element.
     */
    T get(int index);

    /**
     * Returns the index of <code>element</code> in the sorted set.
     * 
     * @param element the query element.
     * @return the index of the query element or -1 if there is no such element
     *         in this set.
     */
    int indexOf(T element);
}
```

**`OrderStatisticTree.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements an order statistic tree which is based on AVL-trees.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 11, 2016)
 * @param <T> the actual element type.
 */
public class OrderStatisticTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
implements OrderStatisticSet<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new TreeIterator();
    }

    private final class TreeIterator implements Iterator<T> {

        private Node<T> previousNode;
        private Node<T> nextNode;
        private int expectedModCount = modCount;

        TreeIterator() {
            if (root == null) {
                nextNode = null;
            } else {
                nextNode = minimumNode(root);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextNode != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (nextNode == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Iteration exceeded.");
            }

            checkConcurrentModification();
            T datum = nextNode.key;
            previousNode = nextNode;
            nextNode = successorOf(nextNode);
            return datum;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            if (previousNode == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        nextNode == null ? 
                            "Not a single call to next(); nothing to remove." :
                            "Removing the same element twice."
                );
            }

            checkConcurrentModification();

            Node<T> x = deleteNode(previousNode);
            fixAfterModification(x, false);

            if (x == nextNode) {
                nextNode = previousNode;
            }

            size--;
            expectedModCount = ++modCount;
            previousNode = null;
        }

        private void checkConcurrentModification() {
            if (expectedModCount != modCount) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException(
                        "The set was modified while iterating.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        Object[] array = new Object[size];
        Iterator<T> iterator = iterator();
        int index = 0;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            array[index++] = iterator.next();
        }

        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        Iterator iterator = iterator();

        if (size > a.length) {
            a = Arrays.copyOf(a, size);
        }

        int index = 0; 

        for (; index < size; ++index) {
            a[index] = (T) iterator.next();
        }

        if (index < a.length) {
            a[index] = null;
        }

        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        for (Object element : c) {
            if (!contains((T) element)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        boolean modified = false;

        for (T element : c) {
            if (add(element)) {
                modified = true;
            }
        }

        return modified;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        if (!c.getClass().equals(HashSet.class.getClass())) {
            c = new HashSet<>(c);
        }

        Iterator<T> iterator = iterator();
        boolean modified = false;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T element = iterator.next();

            if (!c.contains(element)) {
                iterator.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }

        return modified;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean modified = false;

        for (Object element : c) {
            if (remove((T) element)) {
                modified = true;
            }
        }

        return modified;
    }

    private static final class Node<T> {
        T key;

        Node<T> parent;
        Node<T> left;
        Node<T> right;

        int height;
        int count;

        Node(T key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }

    private Node<T> root;
    private int size;
    private int modCount;

    @Override
    public boolean add(T element) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(element, "The input element is null.");

        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node<>(element);
            size = 1;
            modCount++;
            return true;
        }

        Node<T> parent = null;
        Node<T> node = root;
        int cmp;

        while (node != null) {
            cmp = element.compareTo(node.key);

            if (cmp == 0) {
                // The element is already in this tree.
                return false;
            }

            parent = node;

            if (cmp < 0) {
                node = node.left;
            } else {
                node = node.right;
            }
        }

        Node<T> newnode = new Node<>(element);

        if (element.compareTo(parent.key) < 0) {
            parent.left = newnode;
        } else {
            parent.right = newnode;
        }

        newnode.parent = parent;
        size++;
        modCount++;
        Node<T> hi = parent;
        Node<T> lo = newnode;

        while (hi != null) {
            if (hi.left == lo) {
                hi.count++;
            }

            lo = hi;
            hi = hi.parent;
        }

        fixAfterModification(newnode, true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        T element = (T) o;
        Node<T> x = root;
        int cmp;

        while (x != null && (cmp = element.compareTo(x.key)) != 0) {
            if (cmp < 0) {
                x = x.left;
            } else {
                x = x.right;
            }
        }

        return x != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        T element = (T) o;
        Node<T> x = root;
        int cmp;

        while (x != null && (cmp = element.compareTo(x.key)) != 0) {
            if (cmp < 0) {
                x = x.left;
            } else {
                x = x.right;
            }
        }

        if (x == null) {
            return false;
        }

        x = deleteNode(x);
        fixAfterModification(x, false);
        size--;
        modCount++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        checkIndex(index);
        Node<T> node = root;

        while (true) {
            if (index > node.count) { 
                index -= node.count + 1;
                node = node.right;
            } else if (index < node.count) {
                node = node.left;
            } else {
                return node.key;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(T element) {
        Node<T> node = root;

        if (root == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        int rank = root.count;
        int cmp;

        while (node != null) {
            if ((cmp = element.compareTo(node.key)) < 0) {
                if (node.left == null) {
                    return -1;
                }

                rank -= (node.count - node.left.count);
                node = node.left;
            } else if (cmp > 0) {
                if (node.right == null) {
                    return -1;
                }

                rank += 1 + node.right.count;
                node = node.right;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return node == null ? -1 : rank;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        modCount += size;
        root = null;
        size = 0; 
    }

    private Node<T> successorOf(Node<T> node) {
        if (node.right != null) {
            node = node.right;

            while (node.left != null) {
                node = node.left;
            }

            return node;
        }

        Node<T> parent = node.parent;

        while (parent != null && parent.right == node) {
            node = parent;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }

        return parent;
    }

    private void checkIndex(int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The input index is negative: " + index);
        }

        if (index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The input index is too large: " + index +
                    ", the size of this tree is " + size);
        }
    }

    private Node<T> deleteNode(Node<T> node) {
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            // 'node' has no children.
            Node<T> parent = node.parent;

            if (parent == null) {
                // 'node' is the root node of this tree.
                root = null;
                size = 0;
                ++modCount;
                return node;
            }

            Node<T> lo = node;
            Node<T> hi = parent;

            while (hi != null) {
                if (hi.left == lo) {
                    hi.count--;
                }

                lo = hi;
                hi = hi.parent;
            }

            if (node == parent.left) {
                parent.left = null;
            } else {
                parent.right = null;
            }

            return node;
        }

        if (node.left == null || node.right == null) {
            Node<T> child;

            // 'node' has only one child.
            if (node.left != null) {
                child = node.left;
            } else {
                child = node.right;
            }

            Node<T> parent = node.parent;
            child.parent = parent;

            if (parent == null) {
                root = child;
                return node;
            }

            if (node == parent.left) {
                parent.left = child;
            } else {
                parent.right = child;
            }

            Node<T> hi = parent;
            Node<T> lo = child;

            while (hi != null) {
                if (hi.left == lo) {
                    hi.count--;
                }

                lo = hi;
                hi = hi.parent;
            }

            return node;
        }

        // 'node' has both children.
        T tmpKey = node.key;
        Node<T> successor = minimumNode(node.right);
        node.key = successor.key;
        Node<T> child = successor.right;
        Node<T> parent = successor.parent;

        if (parent.left == successor) {
            parent.left = child;
        } else {
            parent.right = child;
        }

        if (child != null) {
            child.parent = parent;
        }

        Node<T> lo = child;
        Node<T> hi = parent;

        while (hi != null) {
            if (hi.left == lo) {
                hi.count--;
            }

            lo = hi;
            hi = hi.parent;
        }

        successor.key = tmpKey;
        return successor;
    }

    private Node<T> minimumNode(Node<T> node) {
        while (node.left != null) {
            node = node.left;
        }

        return node;
    }

    private int height(Node<T> node) {
        return node == null ? -1 : node.height;
    }

    private Node<T> leftRotate(Node<T> node1) {
        Node<T> node2 = node1.right;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.right = node2.left;
        node2.left = node1;

        if (node1.right != null) {
            node1.right.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        node2.count += node1.count + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private Node<T> rightRotate(Node<T> node1) {
        Node<T> node2 = node1.left;
        node2.parent = node1.parent;
        node1.parent = node2;
        node1.left = node2.right;
        node2.right = node1;

        if (node1.left != null) {
            node1.left.parent = node1;
        }

        node1.height = Math.max(height(node1.left), height(node1.right)) + 1;
        node2.height = Math.max(height(node2.left), height(node2.right)) + 1;
        node1.count -= node2.count + 1;
        return node2;
    }

    private Node<T> rightLeftRotate(Node<T> node1) {
        Node<T> node2 = node1.right;
        node1.right = rightRotate(node2);
        return leftRotate(node1);
    }

    private Node<T> leftRightRotate(Node<T> node1) {
        Node<T> node2 = node1.left;
        node1.left = leftRotate(node2);
        return rightRotate(node1);
    }

    // Fixing an insertion: use insertionMode = true.
    // Fixing a deletion: use insertionMode = false.
    private void fixAfterModification(Node<T> node, boolean insertionMode) {
        Node<T> parent = node.parent;
        Node<T> grandParent;
        Node<T> subTree;

        while (parent != null) {
            if (height(parent.left) == height(parent.right) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.left.left) >= height(parent.left.right)) {
                    subTree = rightRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = leftRightRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    root = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height = Math.max(
                            height(grandParent.left),
                            height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                if (insertionMode) {
                    // Whenever fixing after insertion, at most one rotation is
                    // required in order to maintain the balance.
                    return;
                }
            } else if (height(parent.right) == height(parent.left) + 2) {
                grandParent = parent.parent;

                if (height(parent.right.right) >= height(parent.right.left)) {
                    subTree = leftRotate(parent);
                } else {
                    subTree = rightLeftRotate(parent);
                }

                if (grandParent == null) {
                    root = subTree;
                } else if (grandParent.left == parent) {
                    grandParent.left = subTree;
                } else {
                    grandParent.right = subTree;
                }

                if (grandParent != null) {
                    grandParent.height =
                            Math.max(height(grandParent.left),
                                     height(grandParent.right)) + 1;
                }

                if (insertionMode) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            parent.height = Math.max(height(parent.left), 
                                     height(parent.right)) + 1;
            parent = parent.parent;
        }
    }

    public boolean isHealthy() {
        if (root == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return !containsCycles() 
                && heightsAreCorrect() 
                && isBalanced()
                && isWellIndexed();
    }

    private boolean containsCycles() {
        Set<Node<T>> visitedNodes = new HashSet<>();
        return containsCycles(root, visitedNodes);
    }

    private boolean containsCycles(Node<T> current, Set<Node<T>> visitedNodes) {
        if (current == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (visitedNodes.contains(current)) {
            return true;
        }

        visitedNodes.add(current);

        return containsCycles(current.left, visitedNodes) 
                || containsCycles(current.right, visitedNodes);
    }

    private boolean heightsAreCorrect() {
        return getHeight(root) == root.height;
    }

    private int getHeight(Node<T> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        int leftTreeHeight = getHeight(node.left);

        if (leftTreeHeight == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        int rightTreeHeight = getHeight(node.right);

        if (rightTreeHeight == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        if (node.height == Math.max(leftTreeHeight, rightTreeHeight) + 1) {
            return node.height;
        }

        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    private boolean isBalanced() {
        return isBalanced(root);
    }

    private boolean isBalanced(Node<T> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!isBalanced(node.left)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!isBalanced(node.right)) {
            return false;
        }

        int leftHeight  = height(node.left);
        int rightHeight = height(node.right);

        return Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight) < 2;
    }

    private boolean isWellIndexed() {
        return size == count(root);
    }

    private int count(Node<T> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int leftTreeSize = count(node.left);

        if (leftTreeSize == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        if (node.count != leftTreeSize) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        int rightTreeSize = count(node.right);

        if (rightTreeSize == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        return leftTreeSize + 1 + rightTreeSize;
    }
}
```

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

(You can find a unit test and the demo [here](https://github.com/coderodde/OrderStatisticTree).)

Comment: You make me hunt for a true AVL implementation in Java on SE.

Comment: What's so untrue about this one?

Comment: This one, as many others I've seen lately, uses the heights of a node's subtrees, which A-V&L neither know nor care about - just the difference in height, which is kept in the range from -1 to 1.

Comment: And once again, we have to cache (and manipulate) those values -1, 0, 1, so I don't see why the approach you are talking about would be any funkier than this one.